# How to use custom Encoder and Decoder in Quarkus?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket, undertow, quarkus

I have a Quarkus app version 1.2.0.Final. I have such Decoder:

```java
public class UuidDecoder implements Decoder.TextStream<UUID>, Decoder, Decoder.Binary<UUID>, Decoder.Text<UUID> {
    public UuidDecoder() {
        System.out.println("OK!");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(EndpointConfig config) {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public UUID decode(Reader reader) throws DecodeException, IOException {
        return UUID.fromString(CharStreams.toString(reader));
    }

    @Override
    public UUID decode(ByteBuffer bytes) throws DecodeException {
        return UUID.fromString(new String(bytes.array()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willDecode(ByteBuffer bytes) {
        try {
            UUID.fromString(new String(bytes.array()));
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public UUID decode(String s) throws DecodeException {
        return UUID.fromString(s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willDecode(String s) {
        try {
            UUID.fromString(s);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And such Websocket endpoint:

```java
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/api/ws/search/{id}", decoders = UuidDecoder.class)
public class SearchResource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SearchResource.class.getName());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("id") UUID id) {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("We get an open event! ID: %s", id));
    }
}
```

But, for some reason, I can't start my app. In the logs:

```java
14:14:57,999 INFO  [io.und.web.jsr] UT026003: Adding annotated server endpoint class org.siretch.kafka.entrypoint.SearchResource for path /api/ws/search/{id}
14:14:58,113 ERROR [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Failed to start Quarkus: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:193)
    at java.base/java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:417)
    at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:153)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.doStart(DevModeMain.java:178)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:96)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:390)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: UT003028: Could not find decoder for type class java.util.UUID on method public void org.siretch.kafka.entrypoint.SearchResource.onOpen(javax.websocket.Session,java.util.UUID)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder.bootServletContainer(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:445)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.UndertowBuildStep$build32.deploy_0(UndertowBuildStep$build32.zig:171)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.UndertowBuildStep$build32.deploy(UndertowBuildStep$build32.zig:196)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:376)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: UT003028: Could not find decoder for type class java.util.UUID on method public void org.siretch.kafka.entrypoint.SearchResource.onOpen(javax.websocket.Session,java.util.UUID)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap.handleDeployment(Bootstrap.java:101)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.handleExtensions(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:278)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:155)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder.bootServletContainer(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:434)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: UT003028: Could not find decoder for type class java.util.UUID on method public void org.siretch.kafka.entrypoint.SearchResource.onOpen(javax.websocket.Session,java.util.UUID)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.annotated.AnnotatedEndpointFactory$BoundPathParameters.<init>(AnnotatedEndpointFactory.java:399)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.annotated.AnnotatedEndpointFactory.createBoundPathParameters(AnnotatedEndpointFactory.java:258)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.annotated.AnnotatedEndpointFactory.create(AnnotatedEndpointFactory.java:100)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer.addEndpointInternal(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:681)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer.addEndpoint(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:654)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap.handleDeployment(Bootstrap.java:95)
    ... 12 more

14:14:58,114 INFO  [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Attempting to start hot replacement endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
```

So, my question is: how can I register a custom decoder for URL `@PathParam`? I think the problem is in `io.undertow.websockets.jsr.annotated.AnnotatedEndpointFactory.BoundPathParameters#BoundPathParameters` but I'm not sure that I don't do anything wrong.

Edit one: I want to use `java.util.UUID` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons:

1. When adding encoders/decoders, Quarkus checks the implemented interface of your decoder using "else if" instead of "if"; so your class may not implement multiple decoders or multiple encoders. I [filed this as an issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-http/issues/50) and [created a pull request](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-http/pull/51)
2. The current implementation (accidentally?) ignored the list of encoders/decoders. I [filed this as an issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-http/issues/52) and [created a pull request](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-http/pull/53)